Can't paste into vscode
I can't paste into vocode, I have always used cmd+v, but it suddenly stopped working.
I can do cmd+c and paste it to a normal document etc. I have been to editor.action.clipboardPasteAction, where I have cmd+v as a function.
Also my open keyboard shortcuts (JSON) looks like this:
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    { "key": "ctrl+v", "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction" },
    { "key": "cmd+v", "command": "-editor.action.clipboardPasteAction" }
] 


Run the Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting command and report back the results.  It may show that that keybinding is being resolved to something else.

Also get rid of your second keybinding, the one with -editor.action.clipboardPasteAction (the one with the hyphen before the command).  That would disable the command.

I have removed the one with - in front, and got Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting
bash: Toggle: command not found.

I got it! I had som error because I had different commands with cmd+v I think, så after changing these I could paste.
